# Simple java questionnaire using json

Tags: java, json, gson, file-writing

I made a simple questionnaire. I need to write the responses to a JSON file. How to do it?
I use IDEA Intellij and library GSON for work with JSON.
This is main class "Quiz":

```
package questions;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz {
    public static <Outfile> void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String userJson = "[{\"question\": \"1.What is your marital status?\", \"a\": \"(a)Single\", \"b\": \"(b)Married\"}," +
                "{\"question\": \"2.Are you planning on getting married next year?\", \"a\": \"(a)Yes\", \"b\": \"(b)No\"},"+
                "{\"question\": \"3.How long have you been married?\", \"a\": \"(a)Less than a year\", \"b\": \"(b)More than a year\"},"+
                "{\"question\": \"4.Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?\", \"a\": \"(a)Yes\" , \"b\": \"(b)No\"}]";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type questionListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Question>>(){}.getType();

        ArrayList<Question> questionArray = gson.fromJson(userJson, questionListType);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("answer.json");


        for(Question question : questionArray) {
            System.out.println("Question:" + question.question);
            System.out.println("Answer:" + question.a + "   " + question.b);
            Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String answer = keyboardInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println("You got: " + answer);

        }
        
    }}
```

This is class "Question":

```
package questions;
public class Question {

    public String question;
    public String a;
    public String b;

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setAnswer2(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to use FileWriter, but I'm doing it wrong. The output file is empty. Help me, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a FileWriter, but you are never actually writing anything to the file. This is why the file is empty.

```
  string jsonData = "{}";
  FileWriter output = new FileWriter("answer.json");
  // Writes the string to the file
  output.write(jsonData);

  // Closes the writer
  output.close();
```

This would allow you to write contents to a file. Make sure to call `close()` on the FileWriter after writing your content. After that your file `answer.json` should contain:

```
{}
```

Comment: How to write the received answers to a file for each question? My design overwrites the file after each response: `  String jsonData = "{\"Question\": " + question.question + "\"Answer\":" + answer +"}";
            FileWriter output = new FileWriter("answer.json");
            // Writes the string to the file
            output.write(jsonData);

            // Closes the writer
            output.close(); `

Comment: Technically that's a different question, but I'll try to give you some pointers:

1. If you call `fileWriter.write()` multiple times without calling `close()` in between your writes, it should append the contents. 
2. Since your answers should be formatted in JSON it might be more convenient to first build the JSON response in memory and then write it to the file in one `write()` call. 
3. If you don't build the full JSON beforehand you'll have to write `[` before you write the first element and `]` after you write your last element. Every element should be followed by a `,`

Comment: Except for the last element of course :)

Comment: You might want to check out this resource: https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serialize-deserialize-json/
The part you're interested in is the serialize part

Comment: Thanks. I use this: `FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\Users\elements.json")
for (String name : list) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("Name:", name);

    file.write(obj.toJSONString());
}
file.flush();`

Answer (score -2):

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    try {
        String userJson = "[{\"question\": \"1.What is your marital status?\", \"a\": \"(a)Single\", \"b\": \"(b)Married\"}," +
                "{\"question\": \"2.Are you planning on getting married next year?\", \"a\": \"(a)Yes\", \"b\": \"(b)No\"}," +
                "{\"question\": \"3.How long have you been married?\", \"a\": \"(a)Less than a year\", \"b\": \"(b)More than a year\"}," +
                "{\"question\": \"4.Have you celebrated your one year anniversary?\", \"a\": \"(a)Yes\" , \"b\": \"(b)No\"}]";

        JSONArray jsonArray = JSON.parseArray(userJson);
        System.out.println(jsonArray);
        List<Question> javaList = jsonArray.toJavaList(Question.class);
        writeToFile(javaList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void writeToFile(List<Question> data) throws Exception {
    BufferedWriter bw;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\test.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            bw.write(JSON.toJSONString(data.get(i)));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).